# javascript wont work because variable from other page is null (TypeError)

Tags: javascript, typeerror

1. This function works on page1
2. The console says TypeError: lightbox (from function below) is null
3. lightbox is on page2

   ```
   function setBackgroundImg() {
       var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
       var bgImg = document.getElementById("kr-home-bg");
       var x = windowHeight + "px";
       bgImg.setAttribute("style","height:" + x); // line in question when page2 loads 
   }
   setBackgroundImg();
   window.addEventListener("resize", setBackgroundImg);
   ```
4. code below works for page2 when fucntion above is commented out
5. when uncommented: TypeError: bgImg (from function above) is null and    doesn't work
6. bgImg is on page2

   ```
   var lightbox = document.getElementById("lightbox");
   lightbox.style.display = "none"; //line in question when page1 loads
   var lightboxMaker = document.getElementById("enable-lightbox");
   var closeBu = document.getElementById("close-lightbox");
   var lightbox = document.getElementById("lightbox");
   function closeLightbox() {
       lightbox.style.display = "none";
   }
   closeBu.onclick = closeLightbox;

   lightboxMaker.onclick = function() {
       lightbox.style.display = "block";
   };
   ```

Comment: 7. if `getElementById` doesn't find an element, either because it's not in the source at all, or because it runs before the element is loaded in the DOM, it returns `null`

Comment: When you load a new page, it starts with all fresh variables. Variables set in one page do not carry over to the next page.

Comment: If you want persistent data, use cookies or local storage.

Comment: Thanks for the help. For now, I created another script file for the other page. And yes, as I keep learning I will want to write more efficiently. I appreciate the extra tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.getElementById("kr-home-bg")` would have to be available in the DOM when you run `setBackgroundImg()`. The reason this works `onresize` is because the Element does exist at that time. If JavaScript dynamically creates your HTML it will have to occur before you run `setBackgroundImg()` on the first page.

It looks to me like you could solve this with just CSS, since `document.getElementById("kr-home-bg")` takes up the entire window:

```
#kr-home-bg{
  background: url('yourImage.png'); background-size:100%;
}
```

If you have a set width, just put that with a space after it before the `100%`.